# Join multiple tables Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have 3 tables, a purchase (p), a refund (r) and a send to finance software batching table (b).

Set up like this:

```
purchases
=========
order_number VARHCAR(10)
order_id (number)
order_date (date)

refunds
=======
refund_id (number)
order_id <-- relates to purchases table (number)
refund_date (date)

send_to_finance_batch
=====================
generic_id (number) <-- this can be filled in by an number of tables
type (text)
status_reason (text)
satus_id (number)
```

(more or less)

What I need to figure out is how to do a left join (since the generic_id can come from several entities) refunds to purchases?

Right now I have this:

```
SELECT p.order_number,
       b.generic_id,
       b.status_id,
       b.status_reason,
       
FROM send_to_finance_batching b
LEFT JOIN purchases p ON b.generic_id = p.order_id
WHERE...
```

refund_id OR order_id will equal the generic_id so I need to relate generic_id to refund_id and then from the refunds table order_id to orders table.

My desired output is to be able to fill in p.order_number, right now I have the other columns but since order_number only exists on the purchase table id like to link it back to the refunds table by joining on the batching table.

What I have right now is this:

```
Order number | type   | generic_id | status_reason | status_id
==============================================================
             | refund | 1234567890 | 'stuck'       | 99
WH763HWW3499 | purch  | 7534567654 | 'error'       | 99
```

I would like to be able to fill in the order number on the refunds, but since generic_id relates to the refund_id I need to be able to use the order_id from refunds to get the info from purchases and have a complete query

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve].

Comment: Also the desired output would be great.

Comment: I added some details, hopefully that helps to paint a clearer picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Using UNION**

In this case you would lose rows that neither can be joined to purchases nor refunds.

```
SELECT p.order_number,
       b.generic_id,
       b.status_id,
       b.status_reason
FROM send_to_finance_batching b
JOIN purchases p ON b.generic_id = p.order_id
WHERE...

UNION

SELECT p.order_number,
       b.generic_id,
       b.status_id,
       b.status_reason
FROM send_to_finance_batching b
JOIN refunds r ON b.generic_id = r.refund_id
JOIN purchases p ON r.order_id = p.order_id
WHERE...
```

**Option 2: JOIN purchases multiple times and using COALESCE**

```
SELECT coalesce(p.order_number, p2.order_number) order_number,
       b.generic_id,
       b.status_id,
       b.status_reason
FROM send_to_finance_batching b
LEFT JOIN purchases p ON b.generic_id = p.order_id
LEFT JOIN refunds r ON b.generic_id = r.refund_id
LEFT JOIN purchases p2 ON r.order_id = p2.order_id
WHERE...
```

**Option 3: Use COALESCE on JOIN condition**

```
SELECT p.order_number,
       b.generic_id,
       b.status_id,
       b.status_reason
FROM send_to_finance_batching b
LEFT JOIN refunds r ON b.generic_id = r.refund_id
LEFT JOIN purchases p ON coalesce(r.order_id, b.generic_id) = p.order_id
WHERE...
```

Answer (score 0):

Outer join the two tables, but consider the `type` column in order not to join the wrong entity. Then use `COALESCE` to display the order number from the referenced row.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(p.order_id, r.order_id) AS order_id,
  fb.generic_id,
  fb.status_id,
  fb.status_reason
FROM send_to_finance_batching fb
LEFT JOIN purchases p ON fb.generic_id = p.order_id AND fb.type = 'purch'
LEFT JOIN refunds r ON fb.generic_id = r.refund_id AND fb.type = 'refund'
ORDER BY order_id;
```